# Getting "TypeError: (0 , t.useState) is not a function" in console.log when deployed on Netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, netlify

I am trying to deploy a react app using Netlify and the deployment is successful. However, when I go to the URL, the app is blank and has the following error in the console.log.

[screenshot of the console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAV2p.png)

I've tried many things suggested by other threads but cannot seem to solve it, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imported useState from the correct destination. I think you have written

```
import { useState } from "react/cjs/react.development"
```

Replace this with

```
import { useState } from "react"
```